# matrix-scalar multiplication within dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataframe containing cost data and a separate list of matrices that state how each type of cost should be allocated. For the sake of explanation, I'll make some dummy data.

```
library(tidyverse)

# here is my list of cost allocation matrices
matrList <- list(A = cbind(runif(3),runif(3),runif(3)), 
                 B = cbind(runif(3),runif(3),runif(3)), 
                 C = cbind(runif(3),runif(3),runif(3))) %>% 
  lapply(function(x){
    rownames(x) <- c("x","y","z")
    colnames(x) <- c("p","q","r")
    x <- x/sum(x)
  })

# and here is my cost data
mydf <- data.frame(val = runif(8,0,100),
                   lookup = c("A","C","B","B","C","B","C","A"))
```

So each cost is either type A, type B or type C. For each of these types, there is a 3x3 matrix that sums to 1 that states how that cost should be allocated.

I've managed to botch a kind of `left_join` that adds a column to the dataframe containing the appropriate matrices

```
mydf <- mydf %>%
    mutate(propMatrix = lapply(lookup, function(x) matrList[[x]]))
```

This seems to keep the structure of the matrices - great. Only now I want to multiply each `propMatrix` by the corresponding `val` in the dataframe to give me matrices containing the actual allocated costs rather than just the proportions. Optimistically, I thought something simple like `mutate(valMatrix = val*propMatrix)` might work but no.

Does anyone have any smart ideas? I suppose it could be done in a loop as a last resort, but it's not hugely practical given the size of my actual data. I also don't think it's practical to abandon approach of having matrices within the dataframe and put it in long form with replicated rows since each matrix is ~600x100.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `map2`

```
mydf %>%
    mutate(valMatrix = map2(propMatrix, val, `*`))
```

Comment: Well that was straightforward. Thanks!